# "This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated". How to suppress?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm getting this message in watch box.
Actually, my expression doesn't have any side effect, and I need to re-evaluate it automatically each time. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The debugger disagrees with you.  I'm with the debugger, got nothing else to look at.

Comment: @Hans, debugger just doesn't check at all. It only supposes "every method has side effects, every property doesn't". Both is wrong.

Comment: This should probably be tagged with C#. The ",ac" modifier in the accepted answer is only valid in that language. Sources: [Format Specifiers in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby.aspx), [Format Specifiers in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/75w45ekt.aspx)

Comment: I have this problem for C++, so if there's a way to supress the message for C++ I would love to hear it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio: Make debugger aware that a function doesn't cause "side effects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049995/visual-studio-make-debugger-aware-that-a-function-doesnt-cause-side-effects)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can append `,ac` to the watch expression to have it automatically refresh the value

> x.ToString(),ac

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby.aspx for more information and other format specifiers.

thanks to Scott [Visual Studio: Make debugger aware that a function doesn't cause "side effects"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049995/visual-studio-make-debugger-aware-that-a-function-doesnt-cause-side-effects)

Comment: Side note for Googlers: ",ac" is just for C#, not for C++. The return of the usual prodigal son.