# Auto-refresh in watch window in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, watch-window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated”. How to suppress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178647/this-expression-causes-side-effects-and-will-not-be-evaluated-how-to-suppress)

I am using Watch window in Visual Studio.
I have added some variables in Watch window.
Sometimes to get the value while debugging I have to click the refresh icon.
Isn't there some setting that allows it to auto-refresh ?

Answer (score 63):

You can append `,ac` to the watch expression to have it automatically refresh the value.

E.g. Instead of `xyz.ToString()` use `xyz.ToString(),ac`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6814855/1928765) for more information.